# Open a window from NIB in System Preference Pane

Tags: macos, plugins, preferences

I want to open a modal window from NIB, when clicking a button in System Preference Pane.

I build an NIB file. The class of file's owner is NSWindowsController，and its OUTLET 'window' is connected to the target window. Then when I load the window:

```
NSWindowsController *ctl = [[NSWindowsController alloc] initWithWindowsNibName:@"XXX"];
[ctl loadWindow];
```

the stderr shows:
-[NSWindowsController loadWindow] failed to load window nib file 'XXX'

I try to put the NIB in another simple window app, and it can work well.

Anybody knows how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of method "loadWindow" use "window"

```
[[ctl window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:ctl];
```

Comment: `-window` sends `-loadWindow` in case the window hasn’t been loaded yet. If `-loadWindow` cannot load a window as mentioned in the original question, `-window` won’t help.

Comment: I've checked and the result is the same as above.